# Serilog - keep only 7 latest files

Tags: serilog

I use serilog and have the date as a part of my filename. This is an easy way to get to the file. Currently I am checking nightly events and I and just pick the last file in the morning.

Now, I only want to keep 7 days. This is was retainedFileCountLimit is for.
However that does not work as I want it too, as it might check for that specific filename.

How can I do this? (I had my own log system which deleted files older than a week)
Where are all serilog properties described? I am missing an overview of those.

```
        //Add Serilog
           string logFileName = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/new_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log");
           Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .WriteTo.File(
                   path: logFileName,
                   retainedFileCountLimit: 7,
                   shared: true,
                   rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                   rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                   fileSizeLimitBytes: 123456,
                   flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
               .CreateLogger();
           Log.Information("Starting Serilog #1");
```

Answer (score 2):

The [File](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) sink automatically includes the date in the file name - **do not** include `DateTime.Now` in the file name and let Serilog take care of that and you should get the retention that you expect.

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File
    (
        "new_.txt", // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
        retainedFileCountLimit: 7,
        // ...
    )
    .CreateLogger();
```

This will append the time period to the filename, creating a file set like:

```
new_20180631.txt
new_20180701.txt
new_20180702.txt
```

The [documentation of the File sink is the repository on GitHub](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file).